# Tooltip message when hovering on cell with mouse in wx.grid wxpython

Tags: grid, wxpython, tooltip, mousehover

I have a wx.grid table, I want to set a tooltip when I hover on a cell, I tried Mike Driscoll's recommendation below, it works, but I can't select multiple cells with mouse drag anymore, it allows me to select only 1 cell max, please help:

```
self.grid_area.GetGridWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.onMouseOver)

    def onMouseOver(self, event):
        '''
        Method to calculate where the mouse is pointing and
        then set the tooltip dynamically.
        '''

        # Use CalcUnscrolledPosition() to get the mouse position
        # within the
        # entire grid including what's offscreen
        x, y = self.grid_area.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(),event.GetY())

        coords = self.grid_area.XYToCell(x, y)
        # you only need these if you need the value in the cell
        row = coords[0]
        col = coords[1]
        if self.grid_area.GetCellValue(row, col):
            if self.grid_area.GetCellValue(row, col) == "ABC":
                event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("Code is abc")
            elif self.grid_area.GetCellValue(row, col) == "XYZ":
                event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("code is xyz")
            else:
                event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("Unknown code")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found the solution, I have to skip the event:

```
def onMouseOver(self, event):
        '''
        Method to calculate where the mouse is pointing and
        then set the tooltip dynamically.
        '''

        # Use CalcUnscrolledPosition() to get the mouse position
        # within the
        # entire grid including what's offscreen
        x, y = self.grid_area.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(),event.GetY())

        coords = self.grid_area.XYToCell(x, y)
        # you only need these if you need the value in the cell
        row = coords[0]
        col = coords[1]
        if self.grid_area.GetCellValue(row, col):
            if self.grid_area.GetCellValue(row, col) == "ABC":
                event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("Code is abc")
            elif self.grid_area.GetCellValue(row, col) == "XYZ":
                event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("code is xyz")
            else:
                event.GetEventObject().SetToolTipString("Unknown code")   
        event.Skip()
```

Thanks
best regards

Comment: It'd be great if someone could comment on why: what was going wrong, how does this fix it?

Answer (score 1):

@ GreenAsJade
Since I cannot comment due to reputation i am asnwering your question here!

why: what was going wrong, how does this fix it?

If you check the difference between your event Hanlder and @alwbtc's event Handler only difference is event.Skip()

Any time the wx.EVT_xx is bind with custom method in code, wxpython override default definition. For that reason event handling ends in onMouseOver. event.Skip() will propagate the event to _core of wxptyhon allowing it to execute default event handlers.

Hope this answers your question!